# Possible to return a function that takes variable number of parameters

Tags: c#, functional-programming

Is it possible in C# to return a function that takes a variable number of arguments and works in the same way as params works (i.e., as this signature `string Combine(params string[] theRest)`)?

Here is my attempt:

```
 private Func<string[], string> CreateCombineFunction(string baseUrl, char delim)
    {
        return theRest =>
            baseUrl.TrimEnd(delim) + delim +
            string.Join(delim.ToString(), theRest.Select(r => r!.Trim(delim).ToArray());
    }
```

Usage:

```
var combineFunction = CreateCombineFunction("http://blabla/", '/');
var combinedStr = combineFunction(new[] { "this", "works" });
// var combinedStr = combineFunction("this", "does", "not", "work");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a delegate that takes a params argument:

```cs
delegate string Foo(params string[] strings);
```

Use the delegate as return type:

```cs
private Foo CreateCombineFunction(string baseUrl, char delim)
{
    return theRest =>
        baseUrl.TrimEnd(delim) + delim +
        string.Join(delim.ToString(), theRest.Select(r => r.Trim(delim)));
}
```

Invoke the returned delegate:

```cs
var combineFunction = CreateCombineFunction("http://blabla/", '/');
var combinedStr = combineFunction("this", "does", "actually", "work");
```